# How to turn on word wrap in PowerShell ISE editor?

Tags: powershell, editor, word-wrap

It seems that there is no option for word wrapping in this editor - or my vision is somehow completely impaired and my google searches totally misspelled

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2 19042.746 and I can wrap lines in Notepad used natively [among other associations] for editing of BAT files - but I do not have such option in the dedicated editor for PS1 files? How is that possible?

Comment: PS ISE is a code editor & development environment. It is not a Word processor. You can only break PS Code lines at certain places or by using a back tick but again only in certain places. You can adjust the size of the code window by dragging the divider but it will NOT cause lines to wrap. Generally, you can start a new line after an operator (+ - =, etc) or a comma, open/close bracket of some ilk like ( [ {.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I mainly want to see my very long comments without having to scroll sideways

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that whatever I am writing in PowerShell ISE I will have to manually divide into multiple lines, as if I was using a paper with mechanical typewriter and not file within a computer.

That is so lame